# fixed-width center element with auto-expanding elements on both sides

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reproduce the below HTML table construct using CSS3. I have tried various ways of floating elements, creating new rendering contexts, auto margins, inline-blocks etc.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom: 16px;">
    <tr>
        <td>B1, auto-expands</td>
        <td width="175">A, fixed width</td>
        <td>B2, auto-expands</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The end result should be a centered middle element width a fixed absolute width and two elements on the sides that should expand to assume the remaining available width without overlapping the middle element.

I have settled for using CSS’ `display: table|table-row|table-cell`, but I wonder if someone here has a better way of achieving the same result.

Comment: I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/y8CkV/1/

Comment: CSS's family of 'table' display properties is probably your best bet. The only really better option is the CSS Flexbox module, but it's browser support really isn't in a good enough place yet to be overly viable in most cases.

Comment: I’ve been doing front-end development for so many years, and I still think “CSS designers, WHAT WERE YOU THINKING?!” so. many. times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using flexbox?

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>left, auto-expands</li>
    <li class="fix">A, fixed width</li>
    <li>right, auto-expands</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display:    -moz-box;
  display:         box;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
          box-flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
 }

.fix {
  text-align: center;
  width: 175px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
          box-flex: 0;
}
```

- Demo: http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/6
- Demo with Code: http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/6/edit
- Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Flexbox works, I was hesitant because browser support was somewhat spotty, but it’s mostly just prefixes, so that’s acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

Demo: http://cdpn.io/cCaeg

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="links">Left</div>
  <div class="mitte">Center</div>
  <div class="rechts">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.links,
.mitte,
.rechts {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #888;
}

.links {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.rechts {
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.mitte {
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: If I could accept multiple answers, I would accept this one, too. I prefer flexbox because it feels less hacky, but this also fulfills the “requirements” :)

Answer (score 1):

This way also works, Just adjust the percentage accordingly to fill a 100%.
This is how [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) does it..

http://jsfiddle.net/mb2V7/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="b col" id="b1">auto-expand</div>
    <div class="a col" id="a">fixed width</div>
    <div class="b col" id="b2">auto-expand</div>
</div>

.outer { width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto; 

}
*:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a {
    outline: 1px solid green;
    background: #efe;
}
.b {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    background: #fee;

     width: 15%;
}
#a {    
 width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.col{ float:left;}
```

Please also note also, for the boxes to drop down, use

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { .col{ width:90%;
}}
```

Comment: Sorry, I specifically asked about *fixed absolute width*. Percentage widths are easy, but not sufficient :)

Comment: Probably misunderstood, saw there is an upvote, guess thats an answer :) if not will provide one

Answer (score 0):

Here use percentage and float everything to the left:

Here is a link to my Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/y8CkV/2/

```
.outer{
width:100%;
}
#a { 
width: 32%;
float:left;
max-width:180px;
min-width:170px;  }
#b1 {
float: left;
width:32%;}
#b2 {
float: left;
 width:31%;
}
```

this should cover most case scenario as long as you container of the outer div is not changing sizing with a huge difference..

**Another way would be to use inline-block**
http://jsfiddle.net/KK7ZC/

Comment: The center element is not fixed width (although that could be faked by setting min-width = max-width), and the element widths do not add up to 100%, cf. http://jsfiddle.net/y8CkV/3/ which either has the elements not at 100% or wrapping. I’m not sure what the other fiddle is supposed to show – the elements are not next to each other?

Comment: there are so many different solutions, I was showing you an example of a starting point.

Comment: True, but this is not a solution to the question asked, which specifically stated the middle element was to have a fixed and absolute width, and the other elements needed to expand to fill available space.